# Kernel Problems on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I have been trying to work with a jupyter notebook inside vscode, but when I create it the right kernel appears for like 10 seconds and then it disappears.
When I try to check it in the kernels' list I cannot find it.
How to solve this problem?
Many thanks

I have tried multiple times to select the kernel but it is not listed.This problem started yesterday when I download the version 3.11 of python, now it is not even able to find the version I was using before (3.10.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In VSCode navigate to extensions, search for Jupyter and install it.
   Link is [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)
2. Run command prompt as administrator and execute
   `python -m pip install jupyter`
3. Restart VSCode and in the command palette search for Jupyter. You should see an option to select default interpreter, point to your python executable. If you see more than 1 interpreter there then select the one that jupyter is installed in (from 2)

These should hopefully help, but if not then check if python and python/scripts are correctly set up in `PATH`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I randomly swapped to non definitive version of jupyter extension and now it works. I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: Happened to me when I installed python 3.11

Comment: Same, I uninstalled it and put non definitive version of jupyter on VSCode